# How to partially initialize a vector of registers (e.g. some fields of underlying bundle type)

Tags: chisel

Let's say I have a vector of registers like this one (ValidIO is creates a bundle around UInt and adds a "valid" field):

```
val vreg = Reg(Vec(16, ValidIO(UInt(32.W))))
```

What is the best way to only initialize valid fields in all elements of the Vec in a concise way? Now I know how to do it by splitting the registers into two vectors:

```
val vDataReg = Reg(Vec(16, UInt(32.W)))
val vValidReg = RegInit(VecInit(Seq.fill(16) {false.B}))
```

But this is not reusing my original type ValidIO (which may be more complex in general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
val vreg = Reg(Vec(16, ValidIO(UInt(32.W))))
vreg.foreach(_.valid := false.B)
```

I don't know if there's a way to do it in a single line/statement

EDIT: To initialize upon reset

```
val vreg = RegInit(Vec(Seq.fill(16) {
  val w = Wire(ValidIO(UInt(32.W)))
  w.valid := false.B
  w.bits := DontCare
  w
}))
```

A bit verbose but contained in a single block

Comment: I would need something like
    when(reset.toBool)  {
         vreg.foreach(_.valid := false.B)
    }
Right? Then this code depends on reset polarity, which is not great. Or you mean I will reassign them to true.B when i need it, which makes sense.

Comment: For the code snippet after "EDIT: To initialize upon reset", I believe it will initialize ".bits" field of all elements of vreg to 0 too on reset. At least that's what I see in generated firrtl in my version of chisel (e2c5c128f6509805f71aeca790809b3e9a8fe84d). Is that expected? Do you see it in the latest version?

Comment: I've further edited it to mark the bits `DontCare`. In chisel3 master, the code would've errored due to not every field being initialized. In your version, all wires were initialized by default so my code should now be equivalent to not having the `DontCare` in your version. The reason you see 0 for the bits fields is that if a Wire has no connection, FIRRTL will connect it to 0. This behavior is similar to what synthesis tools do. See https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/issues/597 for discussion of this behavior.